# how to add required attribute for input element in react js

Tags: html, reactjs

i am not able make my input field as required field in my js file.

```
<SelectInput
              label="area"
              id="areaName"
              value={areaName}
              onChange={changeArea}
              options={areas}
              required= 'required'
            />

component

import React from "react";

function SelectInput({ id, value, onChange, options, label, disabled }) {
  return (
    <div className="select">
      <label key={id} htmlFor={id}>
        Select {label} :&nbsp;
      </label>
      <select
        value={value}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
      >
        {options?.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.id} value={option.area_name ? option.area_name : option.game_name}>
            {option.area_name ? option.area_name : option.game_name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SelectInput;
```

Question:

As the industry shifts towards microservices architecture for developing large-scale enterprise applications, I find myself navigating through a maze of concepts, patterns, and best practices. While I've read numerous articles, tutorials, and even completed some online courses on the topic, I still feel like there's a vast landscape to explore and understand. Therefore, I'm reaching out to the Stack Overflow community to gain insights from seasoned architects and developers who have hands-on experience with implementing microservices in real-world scenarios.

To provide some context, I'm currently involved in a project where we're transitioning from a monolithic architecture to a microservices-based approach. While the advantages of microservices such as scalability, flexibility, and maintainability are apparent, I'm encountering several challenges and questions along the way, which I hope the community can shed light on.

Service Boundaries and Domain-Driven Design (DDD):

How do you effectively define service boundaries in a complex domain? What strategies or methodologies do you employ to ensure that services are cohesive and loosely coupled?
What role does Domain-Driven Design (DDD) play in identifying and defining microservices? Are there any practical examples or case studies where DDD significantly influenced the success of a microservices architecture?

i am expecting to ge a required field.